# Append list from assoc to another list in Scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp, r5rs

I'm a bit confused on how to append a list that I've gotten from the `assoc` procedure into another list, here is what I have:

```
(define new-list (list 'test))
(define source-a (list '(a foo) '(b bar) '(c hello)))
(append new-list (assoc 'a source-a))
(display new-list)
```

The output is just `(test)` and I'm not sure why it's not `(test a foo)`. Is it possible to append like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `append` is not a mutating function. It returns a *new* list with its arguments appended together. By convention in Scheme, functions that perform mutation end with an exclamation mark, such as `set!`.

You *can* use `set!` to modify `new-list` so that it is updated, like this:

```
(set! new-list (append new-list (assoc 'a source-a)))
```

However, this is highly discouraged in Scheme. While imperative programming makes heavy use of mutation, functional programming languages (including Scheme) try to avoid mutation and side-effects, since those can make programs harder to reason about.

Ideally, you'd just declare a new binding with the new value instead of updating an existing binding. Something like this would work just fine:

```
(define original-list (list 'test))
(define source-a (list '(a foo) '(b bar) '(c hello)))
(define new-list (append original-list (assoc 'a source-a)))
(display new-list)
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now! I'm still new to Scheme and trying to wrap my head around all of it.

Comment: @MannfromReno While the common patterns may be different, do note that there's nothing unique to Scheme here.  In C or Java, etc., the same thing applies.  E.g., if you write `int square( int x ) { return x*x; }`, and then do `int a = 4; square(a); print(a);`, you'll see `4`, not `16`. You'd need to do same thing that you could do in Scheme:  `int a = 4; a = square(a); print(a);`.  There's nothing special about Scheme in this regard.

Comment: Yeah you're right, when passing by value the value will obviously not change. I guess one of those stupid moments when I was just hacking at the keys. Thanks for clarification.